# How to use TOP 1 in JOIN as it returns multiple entries/rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-server-2012

I have below `query` --->

```
    Select * into #MostPopular from                                                                 
 (Select top 10                                                               
 T.RowID as RowID,                                                                 
 CP.PostID,ISNULL(MS.Tagname,'Salud') as TagName                                                         
 from CS_Posts as CP with (nolock)
 INNER JOIN @TempPostIds AS T ON T.PostID = CP.PostID  ----this is temp table which has RowId and PostID                                      
Inner JOIN cs_Posts_InCategories CPC (NOLOCK) ON CPC.PostID=CP.PostID   ---returns multiple categoryIDs as it has multiple entries for single unique PostID
 INNER JOIN SpecialTagContent MS (NOLOCK) ON CPC.CategoryId=MS.CategoryId      -- returns tagname for each unique category ID
 where                                                                
 T.RowID >= @RowID AND T.RowID <= @RowID + @PageSize                                                              
 Order By                                                                
 T.RowID )AS MostPopular                                

select * from #MostPopular
```

**Actual Result** is as below -->

[image]

If you could see the actual result the `ROWID,PostID` are `multiple` because the table `cs_Posts_InCategories` has `multiple entries` for `906477 and so on...`

**Expected Result** is as below -->

[image]

For each `PostID` the `Top 1 tagName` should be returned as shown above..
Could you please help me with the query so that it could return only `TOP 1 Tagname/CategoryID`

**Guess problem with the below query -->**

```
Inner JOIN cs_Posts_InCategories CPC (NOLOCK) ON CPC.PostID=CP.PostID   ---returns multiple categoryIDs as it has multiple entries for single unique PostID
```

**I have also checked using TOP 1 query -->**

```
 ISNULL( TOP 1 MS.Tagname,'Salud') as TagName   ---didnt work for me..
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So, what is the first subexpression that returns an unexpected result? Also please act on [mcve]. Please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method uses `apply`:

```
select top 10 T.RowID as RowID,                                                                 
       CP.PostID, coalesce(MS.Tagname, 'Salud') as TagName
into #MostPopular                                                        
from CS_Posts CP join
     @TempPostIds T 
     on T.PostID = CP.PostID outer apply
     (select top (1) ms.*                          
      from cs_Posts_InCategories CPC join
           SpecialTagContent MS 
           on CPC.CategoryId = MS.CategoryId
      where CPC.PostID = CP.PostID 
     ) ms
where T.RowID >= @RowID and T.RowID <= @RowID + @PageSize                                                              
order By T.RowID;
```

This returns one arbitrary tag.  If there is some ordering then add `order by . . .` into the `apply` subquery.

Comment: Works fine when there is data in the table but not working when there is no data, in this case it returns no row....

Comment: @PB-BitWiser . . . There are three tables in the query, so I don't know which you are referring to.  In your question, all tables have data.  But no doubt either `left join` or `outer apply` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can try by using window function `row_`number()

```
    with cte as        
    (
      Select                                                               
     T.RowID as RowID,                                                                 
     CP.PostID,ISNULL(MS.Tagname,'Salud') as TagName                                                         
     from CS_Posts as CP with (nolock)
     INNER JOIN @TempPostIds AS T ON T.PostID = CP.PostID  ----this is temp table which has RowId and PostID                                      
    Inner JOIN cs_Posts_InCategories CPC (NOLOCK) ON CPC.PostID=CP.PostID   ---returns multiple categoryIDs as it has multiple entries for single unique PostID
     INNER JOIN SpecialTagContent MS (NOLOCK) ON CPC.CategoryId=MS.CategoryId      -- returns tagname for each unique category ID
     where                                                                
     T.RowID >= @RowID AND T.RowID <= @RowID + @PageSize                                                              
     Order By                                                                
     T.RowID 
    ) , cte2 as
    (
     select *,
     row_number() over(partition by ROWID,POSTID order by TagName) rn
     from cte  
    ) select top 10 * from cte2 where rn=1
```

Comment: In this case it will return only `5 rows` while i want to select 10 `rows`

Comment: @PB-BitWiser you shows your expected result 5 rows btw just remove top 10 from 1st query it will applicable for all

Comment: Still it returns 5 rows as the main `cte` returns multiple entries with duplicate ROWIDs

Comment: @PB-BitWiser check latest one if your db has data different than duplicate it will return

Comment: Is there any other way ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182840/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-pb-bitwiser).

Answer (score 1):

Apply `row_mumber` *before* the join:

```
with CPC as
 ( 
   select *,
      row_number()
      over(partition by RowID, PostID
           order by whatever_determines_your_expected_result) as rn
   from cs_Posts_InCategories   --- returns multiple categoryIDs as it has multiple entries for single unique PostID
 )
Select top 10                                                               
   T.RowID as RowID,                                                                 
   CP.PostID,ISNULL(MS.Tagname,'Salud') as TagName                                                         
from CS_Posts as CP with (nolock)
INNER JOIN @TempPostIds AS T ON T.PostID = CP.PostID  ----this is temp table which has RowId and PostID                                      
Inner JOIN CPC ON CPC.PostID=CP.PostID 
INNER JOIN SpecialTagContent MS (NOLOCK) ON CPC.CategoryId=MS.CategoryId  -- returns tagname for each unique category ID
where CPC.rn = 1  -- 
  and T.RowID >= @RowID
  AND T.RowID <= @RowID + @PageSize                                                              
Order By T.RowID
```